# Angularjs not calculating falsy values of 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hey guys i have tow json Array of objects. they contain the property like this
object 1:

```
    $scope.list01 = [
           {
               "key":"00.00","value":"1"
           },{
               "key":"00.15","value":"1.3"
           },{
               "key":"00.30","value":"1.8"
           },{
               "key":"00.45","value":"1.9"
           },{
               "key":"01.00","value":"4"
           },{
               "key":"01.15","value":"3"
           },{
               "key":"01.30","value":"7.5"
           },{
               "key":"01.45","value":"0"
           },{
               "key":"02.00","value":"22.3"
           }];
```

and the other json object

```
   $scope.list02 = [
           {
               "key":"00.00","value":"1"
           },{
               "key":"00.15","value":"1.3"
           },{
               "key":"00.30","value":"1.8"
           },{
               "key":"00.45","value":"1.9"
           },{
               "key":"01.00","value":"0"
           },{
               "key":"01.15","value":"13"
           },{
               "key":"01.30","value":"13"
           },{
               "key":"01.45","value":"13"
           },{
               "key":"02.00","value":"28"
           }
       ];
```

i want to compare the two objects and display the different values in a new array i use angular filters like this

```
        .filter("different",function(){
           return function(input,compares){
               var newArray = [];

               for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                   var foundMatch = false;
                   for(j=0;j<compares.length;j++){
                       if(compares[j].value == input[i].value ){
                          foundMatch = true;
                           newArray.push({
                               value:input[i].value,
                               key:input[i].key

                           })
                           compares[j]++;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if(!foundMatch){
                       newArray.push({
                           value:input[i].value,
                           key:input[i].key

                       })
                   }
               }

               return newArray;
           }
       });
```

and use the filter on my DOM  like this

```
{{compare | differentvalue:filterer}}
```

the problem is the output doesn't contain the zero value.
The filter doesnt get the 0 value whaen i change 0 to '0' the filter works correctly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: i think you might hvae an error in your code. 
what is "compares[j]++"?

Comment: your `value` property is all strings not numbers. Create a demo in plunker. Your problem description is not entirely clear and we don't know what `filterer` looks like. Question is confusing

Comment: here, try to use this template https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/k77rnbfe/

Comment: what do you mean by different value, the value from `list01`or from `list02`?

Comment: i mean i want to compare list01 and list02  and get the values that are not equlal. it want to get the results {
               "key":"01.00","value":"4"
           },{
               "key":"01.15","value":"3"
           },{
               "key":"01.30","value":"7.5"
           },{
               "key":"01.45","value":"0"
           },{
               "key":"02.00","value":"22.3"
           }  which are not in list02

Answer (score 0):

A proposal for returning the values from the first array, if different.

```js
var $scope = { list01: [{ key: "00.00", value: "1" }, { key: "00.15", value: "1.3" }, { key: "00.30", value: "1.8" }, { key: "00.45", value: "1.9" }, { key: "01.00", value: "4" }, { key: "01.15", value: "3" }, { key: "01.30", value: "7.5" }, { key: "01.45", value: "0" }, { key: "02.00", value: "22.3" }], list02: [{ key: "00.00", value: "1" }, { key: "00.15", value: "1.3" }, { key: "00.30", value: "1.8" }, { key: "00.45", value: "1.9" }, { key: "01.00", value: "0" }, { key: "01.15", value: "13" }, { key: "01.30", value: "13" }, { key: "01.45", value: "13" }, { key: "02.00", value: "28" }] },
    result = function (data) {
        var obj = {};
        data.list02.forEach(function (a) {
            obj[a.key] = a;
        });
        return data.list01.filter(function (a) {
            return obj[a.key].value !== a.value;
        });
    }($scope);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```